# How do I check for the existence of a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use an external library in my typescript application, but I also want to load it dynamically if it isn't loaded yet. Currently I have the following:

```
declare var MyLibrary:any;
export class MyLibraryService {
   getInstance () : any {
       if(MyLibrary === undefined) {
           //load the library
       } else {
           return MyLibrary;
       }
   }  
}
```

This throws the following error if MyLibrary doesn't exist yet.

```
ReferenceError: MyLibrary is not defined
```

Is there a way I can check if `MyLibrary` is defined without throwing an exception?

Comment: This may indeed be a duplicate, the ReferenceError exception caught me off guard and I thought it was specific to typescript, but further investigation shows it's just normal javascript behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `typeof`:

```
console.log(typeof FooClass) // undefined
console.log(typeof FooClass === 'undefined') // true
```

I doubt there's any need to use language features specific to TypeScript.